# Using Simple Injector in Web API and OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, simple-injector

I'm experiencing the same problem as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676617/simple-injector-web-api-controller-constructor-injection-failing) and my set up is almost [identical to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002866/unable-to-register-api-controller-using-simple-injector?noredirect=1#comment44800181_26002866) that is actually based on [this guide](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webapiintegration.html). When I access a method in my controller I get this

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'TestController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor.

Here's the stack trace

```
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator
  .Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, 
     Type controllerType)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor
  .CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

And here's the inner exception's stack trace

```
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n  
at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator
   .GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator
   .Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
```

Here's what my controller looks like

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ITestRepo _repo;
    public TestController(ITestRepo repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return _repo.GetId(id);
    }
}
```

And here's how I set up Simple Injector

```
 public class Startup
 {        
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
      // Create the container as usual.
      var container = new Container();
      // Register your types, for instance using the RegisterWebApiRequest
      // extension from the integration package:       
      container.RegisterWebApiRequest<ITestRepo, TestRepo>(); 

     container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

      container.Verify();

      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
            new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

      //
      ConfigureOAuth(app, container);

      var config = new HttpConfiguration();
      WebApiConfig.Register(config);
      app.UseWebApi(config);
   }
}
```

Comment: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/09/28/DependencyInjectionandLifetimeManagementwithASP.NETWebAPI/

Comment: From the stack trace it seems that Simple Injector is *not* involved when resolving controllers. Check what the value of `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver` is at runtime. It is likely being reset somewhere. You need to find out where this happens. In the `WebApiConfig.Register` or `app.UseWebApi` methods perhaps?

Comment: I think it's "involved" because when "container.Verify" is invoked, each of the controllers' ctor is hit. If I understood it correctly that's what "Verify" is for.

Comment: That's incorrect. Although Verify will go through all registrations and check whether they can be created, you need to redirect the default Web API controller creation mechanism to Simple Injector. That's what the `SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver` is for. Web API will use this resolver to create a controller on each request. But if something else changes this resolver (or decides to use a different one), Simple Injector will not be asked to create a controller and you'll fall back to the default behavior of Web API.

Comment: "Verify will go through all registrations and check whether they can be created".... "Web API will use this resolver to create a controller on each request".... That was my understanding, that's what I meant. But thank you for making it more clear.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same issue but with UnityDependencyResolver. But I think it should also work for SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver. Try to register your resolver like this (as a Property of **HttpConfiguration**):

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var container = GetContainer(); // Initialise container

    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration
    {
        DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    };

    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Thanks! How did this solved the problem? Is there a blog somewhere that explains this (in great if there's any).

Comment: @vonv. Like you I was trying to find the solution in different blogs, because also faced the same issue, but finally noticed that in asp.net blog Mike Wasson  sets the dependency resolver on the DependencyResolver property of the global HttpConfiguration object: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection