# SimpleInjector doesn't work - Web API on OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, asp.net-identity-2, simple-injector

OwinStartup.cs

```
public class OwinStartup
{
    internal static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { get; private set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        SimpleInjectorConfig.Configure(app);
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);  
    }

    private static void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(
            () => (IDisposable)GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(
                typeof(AppUserManager)));

        var options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new AppAuthProvider(),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

SimpleInjectorConfig.cs

```
public static class SimpleInjectorConfig
{
    public static void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

        //allows scoped instances to be resolved during OWIN request
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
            {
                await next();
            }
        });

        container.Register<AppIdentityDbContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<AppUserManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register(
            () =>
                container.IsVerifying
                    ? new OwinContext().Authentication
                    : HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication, Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<AppSignInManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.Verify();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
            new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

So in my implemenation of `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` called `AppAuthProvider` Im trying to get instance of `AppUserManager` ( I need to find user ) using this code:

```
var manager = context.OwinContext.Get<AppUserManager>();
```

But dont know why I still get `null`. I really dont know what to do because everythings seems to be configured correctly. Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Simple Injector in Web API and OWIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230951/using-simple-injector-in-web-api-and-owin)

Comment: This helps me but I was still getting `null`. Casting to `AppUserManager` instead of `IDisposable` solve problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Updated code below:

**OwinStartup.cs**

```
 public class OwinStartup
{
    internal static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider { get; private set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
        var container = SimpleInjectorConfig.Configure();

        //allows scoped instances to be resolved during OWIN request
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
            {
                await next();
            }
        });

        var config = new HttpConfiguration
        {
            DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container)
        };

        ConfigureOAuth(app, config);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.UseWebApi(config);  
    }

    private static void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app, HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(
            () => (AppUserManager)config.DependencyResolver.GetService(
                typeof(AppUserManager)));

        var options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new AppAuthProvider(),
            //TODO: Change in production.
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

**SimpleInjectorConfig.cs**

```
 public static class SimpleInjectorConfig
{
    public static Container Configure()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

        container.Register<AppIdentityDbContext>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<AppUserManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register(
            () =>
                container.IsVerifying
                    ? new OwinContext().Authentication
                    : HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication, Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<AppSignInManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

        container.Verify();

        return container;
    }
}
```

Maybe someone will use it.