# SimpleInjector verifies OK, but throws Parameterless constructor error on first request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, simple-injector

I've created a .NET 4.5 WebApi app and I'm attempting to use SimpleInjector.

Everything seems to register OK - when I do `container.Verify()`, my WebApi controller loads with the relevant objects injected into the constructor.

However, when I hit my endpoint, I get the infamous "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'XxxController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

My IoC configuration is below:

**Startup.IoC.cs**

```
public Container ConfigureIoC(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

    RegisterInstances(container);

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
        new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
        {
            await next();
        }
    });

    return container;
}

private void RegisterInstances(Container container)
{
    RegisterWebApiControllers(container);
    // Other registrations here

    container.Verify();
}

private void RegisterWebApiControllers(Container container)
{
    container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
}
```

**Exception**

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'LocationController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

```
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

**InnerException**

> Type 'IP2LocationAPI.Web.Controllers.v1.LocationController' does not have a default constructor

```
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer fixed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28231437/397852

Basically setting the dependency resolver against the `HttpConfiguration` instance rather than the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` method works;

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration
    {
        DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    };
```